# Content-Security-Policy Invalid Command

Tags: apache, command, content-security-policy

I added the following lines to my .htacces file:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-WebKit-CSP: default-src 'self'
```

But I always got the following error:

```
Invalid command 'Content-Security-Policy:', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I don't get it. Which Apache module do I have to activate? What's wrong with these lines?

Thx,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an apache expert, but content security policy is a response header. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html

Answer (score 16):

Add those lines into your httpd.conf configuration files, or inside your virtualhost sections, or inside your .htaccess files:

```
Header unset Content-Security-Policy
Header add Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'"
Header unset X-Content-Security-Policy
Header add X-Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'"
Header unset X-WebKit-CSP
Header add X-WebKit-CSP "default-src 'self'"
```

You may also be interested in adding those headers:

```
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Frame-Options "DENY"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=631138519; includeSubDomains"
```

You have to enable (LoadModule) mod_headers if not already enabled, then restart apache.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Can you explain why you first unset the headers before you set them?

Comment: I guess it is in case they were already set earlier, to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @Bertrand31 doesn't seem necessary as according to the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header) for the `Header set` directive : `The response header is set, replacing any previous header with this name. The value may be a format string.`

Comment: @Bertrand31 to be clearer using the `Header add` directive can result in multiple headers of the same name while `Header set` will not:  `Header add: The response header is added to the existing set of headers, even if this header already exists. This can result in two (or more) headers having the same name. This can lead to unforeseen consequences, and in general set, append or merge should be used instead.`

Comment: also, according to the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet#HTTP_Headers) it is not recommended to use X-Content-Security-Policy or X-WebKit-CSP since `their implementations are obsolete (since Firefox 23, Chrome 25), limited, inconsistent, and incredibly buggy`

Comment: So, in short, we should only use `Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'"` and that's it (plus the domains one wants to specify).